# PHP preg_replace to JavaScript | BBCode

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode

I have regex patterns in **PHP**

```
$s = preg_replace("#\[URL\=(.*)\](.*)\[\/URL\]#Ui", "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>", $s);
$s = preg_replace("#\[CODE\=(.*)\](.*)\[\/CODE\]#Uis", "<pre class=\"brush: $1\">$2</pre>", $s);
$s = preg_replace("#\[URL\](.*)\[\/URL\]#Ui", "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>", $s);
$s = preg_replace("#\[IMG\](.*)\[\/IMG\]#Ui", "<p align='center'><img src=\"$1\" border=\"0\" /></p>", $s);
```

How could I convert those to **JavaScript**?

I tried for this combination but it's not working (?)

```
body.replace(/\[URL\=(.*)\](.*)\[\/URL\]/g, '<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>');
```

**@Kolink**
This is working for single image

```
body = body.replace(/\[IMG\]([\d\D]*)\[\/IMG\]/gi, '<p align="center"><img src="$1" border="0" /></p>');
```

but if I add second image it all crashes becauase in this example

```
[IMG]http://www.someimage.com/123.jpg[/IMG]Test
[IMG]http://www.someimage.com/456.jpg[/IMG]
```

match will be

```
http://www.someimage.com/123.jpg[/IMG]Test[IMG]http://www.someimage.com/456.jpg
```

Comment: What's `body` - a string or DOM object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `i` after the `g` to make the regex case-insensitive.

Additionally, JavaScript doesn't support a "multiline" modifier. Instead, you will need to replace `.` with something like `[\d\D]`.

Comment: `/s` is actually called a single-line modifier. )

Comment: I edited the post. It does not work with multiple codes :/ EDIT: I got it, if I DO NOT replace . (dots) it works.

Comment: Add `?` after the `*`. This will make it handle one image at a time.