# Translate preg_replace with regex in javascript .replace

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I need to translate this php function:
$string = preg_replace('/#([a-z0-9]+)/i', '#$1',$string);
In an equivalent JavaScript .replace function if it's possible.. Thank you..

Comment: Have you tried anything?..

Comment: would you like some ketchup on it sir?

Comment: Very funny.. @Jeff I tried with string=string.replace(('/#([a-z0-9]+)/i', '#$1'); but nothing happen..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140844/php-preg-replace-to-javascript-bbcode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript's `replace` method is almost identical, but it's a method of string instead of its own function

```
$string.replace(/#([a-z0-9]+)/i, '#$1');
```

The only major difference is that JavaScript allows regex literal syntax (with `/`) so the first argument should not be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Thank you. I  delete the quote and it works.